# WPF MVVM Access Element inside ItemsControl DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datatemplate, itemscontrol

I need to get the values from my `ComboBox`es that reside in an `ObservableCollection` being iterated through by an `ItemsControl`. And I need to store them in a separate data structure, at least I think I do. Sounds pretty straightforward? I hope it is, I've been stuck on it all day.

Here's my XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="IVCell" TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Variable.Name}"/>
                        <ComboBox x:Name="IVValues" ItemsSource="{Binding Values}"
                                  SelectedIndex="0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

...
        <ItemsControl Name="IndependentVariables" Style="{StaticResource IVCell}" ItemsSource="{Binding IVCollection}"/>
```

where `IVCollection` is defined here, in my ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<ExternalClass> IVCollection { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Before you ask what `ExternalClass` is, know that that is what contains `Variable` and `Values`.

Here's the problem. I need to get the `SelectedIndex` of `ComboBox` (so I would be changing the current code `SelectedIndex="0"`). And if my `ExternalClass` were what needed to contain those `SelectedIndex` values, that would be easy, since I already have access to its fields (`Variable` and `Value`). But I need those `int` values in

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<int> SelectedIndices { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

or something like that. I had made a quick wrapper class to contain both `SelectedIndices` and `IVCollection`, but obviously that won't work, because `ItemsControl` wants an `ObservableCollection`, not a class with two `ObservableCollection`s.

And I guess the real meat of the question here (I could be wrong, that's why I'm asking) is how do I access a property that's outside of the scope of the `Style`/`DataTemplate` I'm currently in (e.g. `IVCell`)? I can do it in the code-behind with no problem, like so,

```
    private void IVValues_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < IndependentVariables.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            var uiElement = IndependentVariables.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
            var cBox = FindVisualChild<ComboBox>(uiElement); //Homebrew method
            //cBox.SelectedIndex
        }
    }
```

but once again, I'm trying to stay MVVM friendly. I've even tried using event commands with MVVM Light, etc., but that merely postpones the problem. I need to solve it. Or circumvent it.

Comment: So if you manage to bind the selected index values of each ComboBox to you SelectedIndices collection, how will you keep track of which value came from which ComboBox / ExternalClass? It sounds like maybe the length of the items in IVCollection is fixed and thus your intent is to use the index of the value in SelectedIndices, but I'm not entirely clear.

Comment: You need another property or two in the `ExternalClass` to bind against the ComboBox's SelctedItem and/or SelectedIndex to keep track of what items are selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@sleiman and @Brandon
Neither of your answers were 100%, but they were very helpful nonetheless. I reached my solution using elements from both of your answers, so I hesitate to accept one over the other.

I used a combination of the wrapper class solution and the exposed property solution (along with a semi-unrelated but nonetheless necessary event-handling technique) to create the following:

```
public class IVWrapper : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public VariableValueList<double> IVCollection { get; set; }
    private int selectedIndex;
    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get { return selectedIndex; }
        set
        {
            selectedIndex = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedIndex");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

and

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    public ObservableCollection<IVWrapper> IVWrapperCollection { get; set; }

    ...

    private void InitializeIVs()
    {
        IVWrapperCollection.Clear();
        foreach (var iv in ...)
        {
            var toBeAdded = new IVWrapper {IVCollection = iv};
            toBeAdded.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) => Foo();
            IVWrapperCollection.Add(toBeAdded);
        }
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        //Doin stuffs
    }
}
```

This additional integration with my ViewModel allows me to call a function whenever my `selectionIndex` changes. Neat! And clean!

The corresponding changes in the XAML MainView:

```
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding IVCollection.Variable.Name}"/>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding IVCollection.Values}"
                                  SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}"/>
                    </StackPanel>

...

        <ItemsControl Name="IndependentVariables" Style="{StaticResource IVCell}" ItemsSource="{Binding IVWrapperCollection}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

This how I would do it, I would create a property for the selected value

```
// within the MainViewModel class
private ExternalClass _selectedObject;
public ExternalClass SelectedObject
 {
   get { return _selectedObject; }
   set
       {
            _selectedObject= value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedObject");
       }
  }
```

and then bind the `SelectedItem` in the `ComboBox` to the `SelectedObject` property

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding IVCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedObject}" >
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                ... data template goes here
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ComboBox>
```

Hope this will be helpful

Comment: `IVCollection` is a collection of collections. Each item in the `IVCollection` is binding against a ComboBox; in other words, the ComboBox does not bind to the `IVCollection`, at least as described by the OP.

Comment: @MetroSmurf You are correct. Each item in `IVCollection` contains an Independent Variable, where each IV contains its name and a list of its possible Values. In accordance with this answer, I would need an array or list of `SelectedObject`s that could be parsed for each ComboBox's selected value.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way this could be accomplished, although it's not much more MVVM friendly than your example.

In the MainWindow, add the following routed event handler somewhere before your view is shown, like the constructor or loaded event:

```
AddHandler(Selector.SelectionChangedEvent, new SelectionChangedEventHandler(OnSelectionChanged));
```

Then add this handler:

```
private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
     var comboBox = e.OriginalSource as ComboBox;
     if (comboBox == null) return;
     var context = comboBox.DataContext as ExternalClass;
     if (context == null) return;
     var indexOfContext = IVCollection.IndexOf(context);
     if (indexOfContext < 0) return;
     SelectedIndices[indexOfContext] = comboBox.SelectedIndex;
}
```

I'm still not sure how you plan to keep track of which SelectedIndex goes with what data, so in the above example I assumed that the there was a fixed length to SelectedIndices.

If you're looking for a pure data binding solution, I would strongly recommend that you just put a property on ExternalClass and bind to it. Or, if you're opposed to that, use a wrapper class around ExternalClass which exposes ExternalClass as a property and SelectedIndex as another. That would be the easiest and most MVVM friendly way.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. As to the pure data binding solution, I really can't, as I'm not in a position to modify External Class just for this case. Otherwise I would have done that a long time ago! As to the wrapper class solution, if you refer to my question, you'll see I tried that. The problem is `ItemsControl` wants an `ObservableCollection`, not a custom class containing `IVCollection` and `SelectedObject`s. On the other hand, if  I turn `IVCollection` into an `ObservableCollection<CustomClass>`, now I don't know how to access the Variable and Values of `ExternalClass`.